# Unity3D: Raycaster.Raycast on UI, get Worldposition of the hit point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am in UNity3D. I am trying to raycast on UI Element and get the world position of the hit. I have the small test code here. It gives me the name of the target UI Element, but not the position. The world position of the hit is always (0,0,0). Please, can someone suggest, how i can get it right? thank you a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class RaycasterRayScriptTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
    private PointerEventData m_PointerEventData;
    private EventSystem m_EventSystem;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 HitPosition;



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
        m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);
        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit " + result.gameObject.name);
            HitPosition = result.worldPosition;
            Debug.Log("HitPosition " + HitPosition.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. You have to set Canvas Render Mode: Screen Space - Camera. Select the camera, that you have to use for the UI. With this UI-Plane will appear as an GameObject in the world. But the ui-plane position is not adjustable, so you have to move the camera back and adjust the field of view of the camera.

And because the UI-Plane is now an Object, the code
HitPosition = result.worldPosition;
works now.

without the changes on the canvas and camera, the code doesn't work, because plane of ui is virtual and it's position set to the camera position. So if you try to get the worldPosition, it uses the distance betwenn camera and UI-Plane, and since it is zero, you will get zero for the worldPosition as well.